# Replace character string between new lines

Tags: regex, bash, sed, replace, find

I am trying to edit a file such that strings flanked by new lines are removed.

My file looks like:

```
ENSG00000000460_chr1.dat        
varX data data data data data 
varX data data data data data 
varX data data data data data 

ENSG00000005801_chr11.dat        

ENSG00000006007_chr16.dat        

ENSG00000006607_chr2.dat        
varX data data data data data 
varX data data data data data 

ENSG00000010219_chr12.dat        

ENSG00000011052_chr17.dat
```

The output I am trying to get would delete lines which are flanked by new lines (and delete the new lines) resulting in output which looks like:

```
ENSG00000000460_chr1.dat        
varX data data data data data 
varX data data data data data 
varX data data data data data 

ENSG00000006607_chr2.dat        
varX data data data data data 
varX data data data data data
```

I have tried various ideas in sed, but it either returns:

```
sed 's/[\na-zA-Z0-9\n]//g' file.txt | head
_.
. .- . . . . .
. .- . . . . .
-. .- . . . . .
-. .- . . . . .

_.

_.
```

I also tried:

```
sed 's/[\n][a-zA-Z0-9][\n]//g' file.txt | head
```

but this returns the file as is:

```
ENSG00000000460_chr1.dat        
varX data data data data data 
varX data data data data data 
varX data data data data data 

ENSG00000005801_chr11.dat        

ENSG00000006007_chr16.dat        

ENSG00000006607_chr2.dat        
varX data data data data data 
varX data data data data data 

ENSG00000010219_chr12.dat        

ENSG00000011052_chr17.dat
```

Comment: what is your try giving output.

Comment: I never worked with sed, but if it works like normal regex, then I dont understand why so many people do not understand the meaning of `[   ]`.

Comment: `[\na-zA-Z0-9\n]` means: 1 of (\n or letters or numbers)

Comment: please look up what `[ ]` mean. because `[^a-zA-Z0-9$]` means any 1 symbol that is NOT a letter, number or $

Comment: I tried with [ ] also (which I have now added to the example).

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following:

```
awk '/_chr/ && flag{flag=val=""} /_chr/{val=$0;next} val && NF && !/_chr/{if(val){print val;val=""};flag=1} flag;END{if(!flag && val && val!~/chr/){print val}}'  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
/_chr/ && flag{
  flag=val=""
}
/_chr/{
  val=$0
  next
}
val && NF && !/_chr/{
  if(val){
    print val
    val=""
  }
  flag=1
}
flag
END{
  if(!flag && val && val!~/chr/){
    print val}
}'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation too here.

```
awk '
/_chr/ && flag{                   ##Checking condition if string _chr is present in a line and flag is SET then do following.
  flag=val=""                     ##Nullifying variable flag and val here.
}
/_chr/{                           ##Checking if a line has string _chr in it then do following.
  val=$0                          ##Setting variable val value to $0(current line) here.
  next                            ##using next keyword to skip all further statements from here.
}
val && NF && !/_chr/{             ##Checking condition if variable val is SET AND line is NOT NULL and line is not having _chr in it then do following.
  if(val){                        ##If variable val value is NOT NULL then do following.
    print val                     ##Printing variable val here.
    val=""                        ##Nullifing val here.
  }
  flag=1                          ##Setting flag variable to SET here.
}
flag                              ##Checking condition if value of flag is SET then print current line.
END{                              ##Starting END block of awk here.
  if(!flag && val && val!~/chr/){ ##Checking condition if flag is NULL and variable val is SET and val value is NOT _chr then print value of val in next line.
    print val}
}' Input_file                     ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: This does work! May I ask for an explanation as to what it's doing?

Comment: @LynseyHall, on it, will add in few mins.

Comment: @LynseyHall, please check my explanation part and let me know in case of any queries.

Answer (score 1):

**general note:** the following solutions require that you use Unix line-endings (`\n`) and not Dos line-endings (`\r\n`). From copying the input, Dos line-endings were observed. (`dos2unix` might come in handy)

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="\n";ORS="\n\n"}(NF>1)' file  # introduces extra line at end
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="\n";}(NF>1){print (p?"\n":"")$0;p=1}' file  # no extra line
```

**How does it work:** By setting the record separator `RS` to be empty, all *paragraphs* are considered to be records. The question is, how many lines do they have. The answer is given by counting the number of fields in one record, where each field is separated by the field separator `FS="\n"`. So if the number of fields `NF` per record is bigger then one, we want to print the record.

```
sed  '/^$/!{H;d};{x;/.\n/!d}' file                # introduces extra line at start
```

**How does it work:** SED has two memories. The pattern space is where you do all operations on and the hold space is a long-term memory. The idea is to always have an empty pattern space and append all text to the hold space using `H`. If a new line is read and the pattern space remains empty. Process the hold space by swapping it with the pattern space (`x`). If it contains a character followed by a newline, print it otherwise delete it.

---

**awk:**

> **RS:** The first character of the string value of `RS` shall be the input record separator; a <newline> by default. If `RS` contains more than one character, the results are unspecified. *If `RS` is null, then records are separated by sequences consisting of a <newline> plus one or more blank lines, leading or trailing blank lines shall not result in empty records at the beginning or end of the input, and a <newline> shall always be a field separator, no matter what the value of `FS` is.*
>
> **FS:** Input field separator regular expression; a <space> by default.
>
> **ORS:** The print statement output record separator; a <newline> by default.
>
> **<sub>source: [Posix AWK standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)</sub>**

**sed:**

> **[2addr]d:** Delete the pattern space and start the next cycle.
>
> **[2addr]H:** Append to the hold space a <newline> followed by the contents of the pattern space.
>
> **[2addr]x:** Exchange the contents of the pattern and hold spaces.
>
> **<sub>source: [Posix SED standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)</sub>**

Comment: I think this is missing a quote before \n in FS=\n". I tried this just now and it just returns the file unchanged.

Comment: @LynseyHall yes indeed. fixed

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!{N;/^$/M!ba};/\n./!d' file
```

Gather up lines in the pattern space until the end of file or an empty line. If the collection has two or more non-empty lines do not delete them i.e. print those collections. Collections consisting of a single line followed by an empty line are deleted.

Comment: I was waiting for someone to chime in with a nice `sed` solution as I couldn't come up with anything elegant myself. After reading the manual, I am still left a bit confused by the `M` modifier. Would you please elaborate on that? :)

Comment: @PesaThe the `M` flag following a regexp in GNU sed is the multiline flag. It allows the use of `^` and `$` to represent start and end of a line when the pattern space contains `\n`'s usually introduced by way of the `N`, `H` , `G` and the substitute/transpose commands. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. ++ for nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution, but here is another `awk` solution:

```
awk '/^$/{c=0;next} ++c==2{print (f++?RS:"") s} {s=$0} c>1' file
```